# Only getting 15-16 volts from Furnace R and C

Tags: hvac, electrical-panel, thermostat, furnace, thermostat-c-wire

I recently purchased a smart thermostat. Because it needed a common wire and I only had a 3 wire setup, I ran a new thermostat wire to my furnace. However, I now get only 15 volts (inconsistently, sometimes I'm getting 0 volts) between the R and C wires where I was going to connect to my new thermostat.

I then went to the furnace and tested the R and C contact and again only get 15 volts (again, at certain times I'll get nothing). The status code is blinking a code 24 for this Bryant unit which supposedly corresponds to "Secondary voltage fuse is Open - check for short circuit in secondary voltage (24vac) wiring". However, if it was a blown 3amp fuse, wouldn't I get no voltage on the contacts and not the reduced voltage that I am getting? Any thoughts on what this could be? Could it be the transformer?

[image: zoomed in circuit board]
[image: Zoomed out circuit board]

Comment: Can you measure the voltage directly from the transformer?

Comment: I can try. I think the blue and red wires central in the photo from my posting are coming straight from the secondary on the transformer. Can I pop those off and test across those? Or is it advised to try to test directly on the leads at the transformer (which is a little harder to access given the arrangement.

Comment: Testing the end of the wires would be fine.

Comment: While you're in testing, can you pull the fuse out and check it for continuity, just to rule it out as a cause of this issue?

Comment: Went back under the house and tested the low voltage side of the transformer which showed 28 volts. tested the fuse and it was intermittent 15-16 and looked blown. Replaced the 3amp fuse and voila 28 volts at the R-C. Not sure how I was getting 15 volts with a blown fuse, but in any event the issue seems to be resolved. Thanks for the help.

Comment: yeah, you might think a fuse is going to be a clean break, and normally it is.  But, sometimes a temp short will vaporize the metal in the fuse, then it can still conduct, maybe acting more like a resistor.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this question was posted as a [comment by the OP](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/172227/only-getting-15-16-volts-from-furnace-r-and-c#comment295423_172227):

> Went back under the house and tested the low voltage side of the transformer which showed 28 volts. tested the fuse and it was intermittent 15-16 and looked blown. Replaced the 3amp fuse and voila 28 volts at the R-C. Not sure how I was getting 15 volts with a blown fuse, but in any event the issue seems to be resolved. Thanks for the help.

*Posted here so this question has an actual answer that new comers can up vote instead of posting "thank you" non-answers.*